# Custom view in toolbar called from Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

Trying to add a custom view in a toolbar from a fragment. It was initially an activity and that worked nicely, but needed to change to fragment and now I am confused.

This is in my layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_menu"
            style="@style/spinner_style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@string/search" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/customView"
            layout="@layout/custom_view" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In activity class :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setTitle("");
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

menuView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.customView);
```

...

But in my Fragment i have this:

```
mActionBar =  ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
if(mActionBar != null) {
        mActionBar.setTitle("");
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
}
```

Which is fine because it shows the toolbar BUT, how can i add the custom view instead of toolbar title? It will be a spinner and a textView (etc). As you can see from photo, it is situated below the title. My appologies if this is a silly question...

[image: Ups]